# Ослушаться кого - винительный или родительный?

Tags: грамматика, управление, родительный-или-винительный

"Иран ослушался Кремль" - фраза резанула своей неуклюжестью.
Но не "Кремля" же, если исходить из того, что "Кремль" даже в переносном значении неодушевлен, а падеж тут очевидно винительный. Да, в текстах всякое встречается но нормативен винительный, нет?

Кто не верит в винительный. "Иран ослушался Москву" - так ведь? "Не Москвы"?

"Ослушался Папы" - Результатов: примерно 4 210 
"Ослушался Папу" - Результатов: 83
(С) Гугл.

Ну никак не получается, что здесь однозначно родительный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, "ослушаться Кремля", "ослушаться Москвы", но "ослушаться Папы". 
Все просто.
Ослушаться - глагол "ждательной" группы. И он требует "ждательного" падежа.
Этот падеж во всех родах и числах совпадает с винительным для одушевленных объектов и с родительным для неодушевленных.
Сравните: ждать трамвая (некоторого), жать решения, но: ждать сестру, помощника.

Смотрите Зализняка.
https://books.google.ru/books?id=_6ZCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9#v=onepage&q=%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&f=false

Comment: Интересная мысль.

Comment: Глагол ждать - переходный, он может управлять В.п. и Р.п., а ослушаться - непереходный, управляет только Р.п.

Comment: Sergey, опять ерунду написали. Непереходные глаголы тоже могут управлять винительным падежом. Вы спутали причину и следствие. Но здесь-то это вообще не имеет отношения к разговору.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите пример, из которого будет ясно, что непереходный глагол управляет беспредложным В.п. И заодно  почитайте определение непереходного глагола (в любой книжке, какую найдете). У меня вот  в руках "Морфология современного русского языка для вузов (2009), и там написано: Непереходные глаголы - это глаголы, не обладающие свойством переходности, то есть НЕ УПРАВЛЯЮЩИЕ В.п. (или Р.п. при отрицании).

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, "Кремля". Но при том все-таки, наверное, "Москвы". 
Но и "Папы" тоже куда как естественнее.

Comment: Ну хорошо, пусть будет Кремля. А почему? На родительный меня не уговаривайте, пока не объясните Папу. На одушевленность - по тем же причинам. С Москвой тут еще можно какие-то варианты найти.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: Иран ослушался Кремля. Иран ослушался Москвы.

ОСЛУШАТЬСЯ, кого-чего. Разг. Не подчиниться чьему-л. приказу, требованию, распоряжению. О. родителей. О. приказа. Посмей только ослушаться меня!

Это Р.п., с категорией одушевленности не связан. Глагол непереходный, не может иметь дополнение  в форме В.п.

Comment: Ну что вы в самом деле, Кузнецова предлагаете как аргумент в грамматическом вопросе? Хоть бы ссылку давали, что ли...

Comment: Sergey, Это Р.п., с категорией одушевленности не связан. - РП-то не связан. Вопрос в том, что для одушевленных объектов м.р. он совпадает с винительным, а для неодушевленных - нет..

Comment: 1. Кузнецов - это всего лишь словарь, где утверждается, что глагол ослушаться управляет только Р.п. Но это очевидно следует из того, что возвратный глагол всегда непереходный и не может иметь при себе прямой объект в форме В.п. 2. Итак, это Р.п., а Р.п. не выражает категорию одушевленности, ее выражает только В.п, который использует ФОРМУ Р.п для одушевленных сущ. 3. Правильно говорить: ослушаться Папы, но многие говорят неверно: ослушаться Папу.  Происходит смешение форм: не слушать Папы/Папу, мамы/маму (колебание  Р.п), и эта форма переносится на "ослушаться Папу".

Comment: Кузнецов - это всего лишь **толковый** словарь. Морковкин прав, что посмотрел у Зализняка.

Comment: При чем тут глагол ждать и ждательный падеж?  Надо уточнить, но, скорее всего, ждательным называют разновидность Р.п., который может заменять В.п. Только всё это касается ПЕРЕХОДНЫХ ГЛАГОЛОВ, а "ослушаться" - непереходный глагол. Так что, по-вашему, непереходный глагол может иметь прямое дополнение в В.п.?

Comment: Может, переходный глагол - этот тот, который образует страдательное причастие. А "винительный без предлога" - это всего лишь  свойство, не абсолютное. По этой терминологии, например,  "пить" и "есть"  - глаголы не переходные.

Comment: Переходные глаголы (по определению) обозначают действие, направленное на объект, причем этот объект выражается сущ. в форме беспредложного В.п. Глаголы пить, есть - переходные, без объекта они не имеют смысла. А образование страдательных причастий следует из переходности глагола (они обозначают признак предмета, над которым совершается действие).

Comment: Я бы предпочел СВОЕ определение, конструктивное. Но спорить не буду. Вы можете пользоваться своим.

Comment: Это не мое определение, оно взято из Грамматики под ред. Лопатина. Я предпочитаю пользоваться не своей, а официальной терминологией.

Comment: *а официальной терминологией* - тогда прошу назвать документ и официальный орган утвердивший данную терминологию в рамках своей компетенции. И заодно, какие меры будут применяться к тем, кто пользуется терминологией, отличающейся от вашей.

Comment: Определения - это святое, на их основе строится  любая наука, любая наука начинается с определений. Например, разные определения параллельных прямых лежат, условно говоря,  в основе  геометрий Евклида и Лобачевского. Так что у математиков геометрия Евклида, а у нас грамматика Лопатина, поэтому будьте любезны соответствовать. Если люди изначально будут говорить о разных вещах, то у них нет никаких шансов понять друг друга. Имея СВОИ  определения, можно говорить только самому с собой.